# Automatizar la descarga de un PDF de una pagina web en c#

Tags: c#, web, pdf

estoy tratando de descargar en pdf los precios de combustibles pemex.

https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=6

el problema es que cuando entro en la pagina web si me lo descarga pero cuando quiero añadirlo a codigo c# para que haga el proceso automaticamente solo me descargar un html que dice que no se pudo mostrar el documento, tenia pensado automatizar el proceso ya que necesito que automaticamente saque los precios diariamente de ese archivo, saludos.

este es mi codigo:

```
 string url = @"https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=1";
            try
            {
                WebClient cliente = new WebClient();
                cliente.DownloadFile(url, @"c:\Temp\mypdf.pdf");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
            }
```

Comment: la pagina tendra alguna validacion de sesion supongo porque a mi tambien me sale que no se puede ver el archivo

Comment: https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/menu/controlador?Destino=menu_gral.jsp esa es la pagina antes de la visualizacion del archivo y de ahi das click en precios vigentes y desde ahi si aparece

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solucion en otro post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44012181/10919192

y el codigo que me quedo fue:

```
 WebClientEx MyCliente1 = new WebClientEx();
            WebClientEx MyCliente2 = new WebClientEx();
            MyCliente2.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            MyCliente2.OpenRead(@"https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/menu/controlador?Destino=menu_gral.jsp");
            MyCliente2.CookieContainer = MyCliente2.CookieContainer;
            MyCliente2.DownloadFile(@"https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=1", "PRECIOS.PDF");
```